# I need to show my App in UIActivityViewController for All Applications as Action Extension(Default)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, uiactivityviewcontroller

Created New Project and Added ActionExtension it worked and shows in Action Activities But Action Extension doesn't show in Device when i created for Existing App(Old App which contains swift and Objective-c Files)
I need to show my App in Action Extension of UiactivityController but i am unable to show For Every Application in Device  refer image

[image: image1] [image: image2]

***Query : While in Simulator(Photos App) it shows and it Doesn't shows in Other Apps in Simulator but when i run in Device it Doesn't shows in both Photos App and others

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Get the item[s] we're handling from the extension context.

    // For example, look for an image and place it into an image view.
    // Replace this with something appropriate for the type[s] your extension supports.
    var imageFound = false
    for item: AnyObject in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
        let inputItem = item as! NSExtensionItem
        for provider: AnyObject in inputItem.attachments! {
            let itemProvider = provider as! NSItemProvider
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
                // This is an image. We'll load it, then place it in our image view.
                weak var weakImageView = self.imageView
                itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error) in
                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {


                        if let strongImageView = weakImageView {

                            if let imageURL = image as? NSURL{
                                strongImageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)!)
                            }else{

                strongImageView.image = image as? UIImage
                            }
                        }

                    }
                })

                imageFound = true
                break
            }
        }

        if (imageFound) {
            // We only handle one image, so stop looking for more.
            break
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func done() {
    // Return any edited content to the host app.
    // This template doesn't do anything, so we just echo the passed in items.
    self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems(self.extensionContext!.inputItems, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Referred Apple Documentation and other links

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794

on Extensions didn't find any relevant answer
and  my Action Extension Plist File (refer image)

[image]

**I am unable to show my app in UiactivityViewController Please Help

Comment: follow same as [share excel file from one application to another application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33542734/1106035)

Comment: thats totally different to Extensions @PareshNavadiya

Answer (score 15):

Now, I am able to show my AppExtension in UIActivityViewController

I took  my Old Project again and added Target -> Action Extension Newly

### How to add Target?

Xcode -> File -> create New Target -> select Action Extension -> Done

### Things to do in .plist:

In Plist Added like shown in Png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBwdil.png

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
</dict>
```

## Result:

[image]

Refer links

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794

http://www.appcoda.com/tag/app-extension/